# What is a succinct positive name for a busybody ( non impacted stakeholder )?

Tags: terminology, names, synonyms

I am looking for a word that *does not* have a negative connotation and is a succinct general term for a: non user, but vocal, stakeholder.

**Arbitrary example:**

Say a new road was going to be built through an area. What would you call a person who is not directly impacted (lives in a different area) but would make a submission (for / against) its construction? e.g., "It will give the elderly better access to X resource", "It will harm Y bird's migration path."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general legal term would be an **advocate**.

> a person who publicly supports or recommends a particular cause or
>   policy.

Another legal term that I don't think meets your scenario is *guardian* but is often used for a person that watches over another person or public interest.

Two very similar words that have less legalese are *champion* or *crusader*.

Answer (score 3):

I would say they are an **interested observer**.

That distinguishes them from an *[interested party](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/interested-party)*, who is clearly involved in the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Describing them as being "community minded" would be a way of putting a positive spin on it.